# After Delete Mutation not Refetching Query (Apollo Graphql & Nextjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I recently switched my reactjs code to nextjs code, and I've observed that while I'm in reactjs code, When I delete data or perform a delete action, it appears like the queries are re-fetched and I am given the most recent or updated data in the datatable, but when I attempt it on Nextjs, it does not work. Is there a way to fix this?

Keep note I am using client side for this action.

## Code

---

### Form.js

```
export default function MainCategoryForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("");

  const [createMainCategory, { loading }] = useMutation(
    CREATE_MAINCATEGORY_MUTATION
  );

  async function onSubmit() {
    const res = await createMainCategory({
      variables: {
        name,
        slug: name.toLowerCase(),
        file,
        status,
      },
      update: (cache, { data: { createMainCategory } }) => {
        const { mainCategories } = cache.readQuery({
          query: FETCH_MAINCATEGORIES_QUERY,
        });
        cache.writeQuery({
          query: FETCH_MAINCATEGORIES_QUERY,
          data: { mainCategories: mainCategories.concat([createMainCategory]) },
        });
      },
      refetchQueries: [{ query: FETCH_MAINCATEGORIES_QUERY }],
    });
    if (res) {
      toast.success(`Main Category Created`, { autoClose: 2000 });
      setName("");
      setStatus("");
      setFile("");
    }
  }

  console.log(file);

  return (
    <>
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} className={loading ? "loading" : ""}>
        <h2>Create a Main Category:</h2>
        <Form.Field>
          <input
            name="file"
            type="file"
            onChange={(event) => {
              setFile(event.target.files[0]);
            }}
          />
          <Form.Input
            placeholder="Please Enter Name"
            name="name"
            label="Name: "
            onChange={(event) => {
              setName(event.target.value);
            }}
            value={name}
          />
          <label>Status: </label>
          <select
            name="category"
            className="form-control"
            onChange={(event) => {
              setStatus(event.target.value);
            }}
            value={status}
          >
            <option active="true" hidden>
              Please Enter Status
            </option>

            <option value="Activated">Activated</option>
          </select>
          <br />

          <Button type="submit" color="teal">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Field>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}
```

As shown above this code I have this `refetchQueries: [{ query: FETCH_MAINCATEGORIES_QUERY }]`, in which after the add mutation or mutation it will refetch the query needed for the recent data to show in my datatable, I tried also putting that in the DeleteButton Component but it doesn't work.

### Table

```
export default function MainCategoryTable({
  mainCategory: { id, name, slug, status, url, createdAt },
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <tr>
        <td>{id}</td>
        <td>
          <img src={url} width={300} />
        </td>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{slug}</td>
        <td>{status}</td>
        <td>{dayjs(createdAt).format("h:mm:ss a")}</td>
        <td>
          <DeleteButton name={name} mainCategoryId={id} />
          <Button>
            <Link href={`/mainCategories/${id}`}>
              <Icon name="edit" style={{ margin: 0 }} />
            </Link>
          </Button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </>
  );
}
```

### DeleteButton Component

```
export default function DeleteButton({ mainCategoryId, callback }) {
  const [confirmOpen, setConfirmOpen] = useState(false);

  const mutation = DELETE_MAINCATEGORY_MUTATION;

  const [deleteMainCategoryOrMutation] = useMutation(mutation, {
    update(proxy) {
      setConfirmOpen(false);
      if (mainCategoryId) {
        const data = proxy.readQuery({
          query: FETCH_MAINCATEGORIES_QUERY,
        });
        data.getMainCategories = data.getMainCategories.filter(
          (ap) => ap.id !== mainCategoryId
        );
        toast.error(`Main Category Deleted`, { autoClose: 2000 });
        proxy.writeQuery({ query: FETCH_MAINCATEGORIES_QUERY, data });
      }
      if (callback) callback();
    },
    variables: {
      mainCategoryId,
    },
  });
  return (
    <>
      <MyPopup content={"Delete Main Category"}>
        <Button
          as="div"
          color="red"
          floated="right"
          onClick={() => setConfirmOpen(true)}
        >
          <Icon name="trash" style={{ margin: 0 }} />
        </Button>
      </MyPopup>
      <Confirm
        open={confirmOpen}
        onCancel={() => setConfirmOpen(false)}
        onConfirm={deleteMainCategoryOrMutation}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

If you need any more code, such as my backend or any files to figure out what's wrong, I'll always amend my article. If you need any clarification or don't understand what I mean, please leave a comment down below.

Comment: no category query/rendering - nothing to update ... rendered server side (SSR)?

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have edited my post @xadm I think you will find ur answer there if not please comment here :)) thanks again

Comment: Have you tried to set/change the `fetchPolicy` of `FETCH_MAINCATEGORIES_QUERY` query to `network-only` or `cache-and-network` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Fraction I have changed it a while ago but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the [`refetchQueries`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#refetching-queries) in the `DELETE_MAINCATEGORY_MUTATION` mutation, instead you used the [`update`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#the-update-function) option and read the query from the cache but you mutated the data, which is not the right way to do it, instead you should return a new array as follows:

```
const [deleteMainCategoryOrMutation] = useMutation(mutation, {
    update(proxy) {
      setConfirmOpen(false);
      if (mainCategoryId) {
        const previousData = proxy.readQuery({ query: FETCH_MAINCATEGORIES_QUERY });
        const getMainCategories = previousData.getMainCategories.filter(
          (ap) => ap.id !== mainCategoryId
        );
        const data = {
          getMainCategories,
        };
        toast.error(`Main Category Deleted`, { autoClose: 2000 });
        proxy.writeQuery({ query: FETCH_MAINCATEGORIES_QUERY, data });
      }
      if (callback) callback();
    },
    variables: {
      mainCategoryId,
    },
  });
```